# RESTful API design: reasonable to accept unique identifiers rather than resource URIs?

Tags: api, rest, hypermedia

Are there disadvantages to allowing a RESTful API to accept a representation with an implicit link to another resource?

To illustrate this, take that I have two resources:

```
GET /people/:id
GET /houses/:id
```

A person has a unique identifier in addition to `id`, which is their `email`.

Are there disadvantages to allowing the following interaction?

```
POST /houses
{
    "_links": {
        "owner": {
            "email": "example@example.com"
        }
    },
    "street_number": 20
}
```

The server know that the email field is unique, and therefore can be used to identify the `people` resource. It will create an association to that person.

The **reason** to allow this would be to make it easier on the API client, where they don't have to first look up the URI of the resource.

In contrast, I would certainly allow this type of call:

```
POST /houses
{
    "_links": {
        "owner": {
            "href": "/people/3"
        }
    },
    "street_number": 20
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common sense should drive here. If in your business model the user has a unique email, there is no drawback for me.